# Task.WhenAll() - cannot add collection of tasks - async/await

Tags: async-await

I'm trying to use async/await to run long running tasks in parallel and run them at the same time but I cannot add the tasks to the task collection and add them to the Task.WhenAll() because it immediately starts running the tasks. I have the following code:

```
var task1 = _bll.longRunningTask1().ConfigureAwait(false);
var task2 = _bll.longRunningTask2().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The above long running tasks are already running by this point so cannot first store them in a collection and then put them into Task.WhenAll() and then run them. **What is the correct way of doing this to get them into the collection and run them only with the Task.WhenAll()?**

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(task1);
tasks.Add(task2);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to use async/await to ... run them at the same time

You can do asynchronous concurrency by using `Task.WhenAll`.

> The above long running tasks are already running by this point so cannot first store them in a collection and then put them into Task.WhenAll() and then run them.

`Task.WhenAll` does not run tasks. `Task.WhenAll` merely (asynchronously) waits for multiple tasks to complete.

> What is the correct way of doing this

It's the code you already have:

```
var task1 = _bll.longRunningTask1().ConfigureAwait(false);
var task2 = _bll.longRunningTask2().ConfigureAwait(false);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

which is pretty much equivalent to explicitly creating a `List<T>`:

```
var task1 = _bll.longRunningTask1().ConfigureAwait(false);
var task2 = _bll.longRunningTask2().ConfigureAwait(false);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(task1);
tasks.Add(task2);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Either of these should work just fine.